# l3color's colors: unusable with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, expl3

In the following MCE, the `myred` color is defined thanks to `l3color` syntax (`\color_set:nnn {myred} {rgb} {1,0,0}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tikz \draw[red] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
%
\color_set:nnn {myred} {rgb} {1,0,0}
\color_fill:n { myred }
\draw_begin:
\draw_path_circle:nn {0,0} {10pt}
\draw_path_use_clear:n { draw }
\draw_end:
%
% \tikz \draw[myred] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

This color works well e.g. in a `l3draw`'s drawing but not in a `tikz`'s drawing, as one can see by uncommenting the instruction `\tikz \draw[myred] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];`, the error being:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/myred' and I am going to
> ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Is there a way to make `l3color`'s colors usable with `tikz`?

Comment: `\color_set:nnn{myred}{rgb}{1,0,0}` doesn't make `myred` usable with `xcolor`.

Comment: @egreg So, hopeless?

Comment: it is currently hopeless, but it is certainly in the pipeline (I have a branch in xcolor, where I try to unify them, but it is not trivial).

Comment: Side remark: one requirement to really unify both, is that tikz stops to use internals see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1244

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Colors defined with `\color_set:nnn` are not usable with `xcolor`. Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\color_set:nnn { myred } { rgb } { 1,0,0 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textcolor{myred}{Test}

\end{document}
```

This results in

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `myred'.
```

You can define your own version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_color_set:nnn
 {
  \color_set:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \definecolor { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tikz \draw[red] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];

\ExplSyntaxOn
\db_color_set:nnn {myred} {rgb} {1,0,0}
\color_fill:n { myred }
\draw_begin:
\draw_path_circle:nn {0,0} {10pt}
\draw_path_use_clear:n { draw }
\draw_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikz \draw[color=myred] (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];

\end{document}
```

[image]